# How to add arrow in an active navbar class in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add downward arrow to my active navbar.

[image]

I am using following code :

```
.navbar-custom .active
{
    background-color: #728C00;  
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

But, it does not work properly.